# Sending email programmatically using browser authentication

Tags: authentication, email, gmail

I want to send email using google server programmatically, I do not want to supply the program with my user and password but rather would want the program to use the browser "normal" authentication if required or use the current session where I'm already logged in.

is that possible?

Saw plain text examples, which I can pass as an env variable but as described I want to use the browser authentication mechanism.

thanks